# Dividing each column of a dataframe by all columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two dataframes called "data" and "benchmark". "Data" consists of four time series A, B, C and D. "Benchmark" consists of five time series B1, B2, B3, B4, B5.

I want to divide each column of "data" by all columns of "benchmark". So, in total I get 20 time series. When I try the following code, I get the error message that I selected undifined columns.

```
benchmark <- read.csv("benchmark.csv") # Read in benchmark data
benchmark.names <- colnames(benchmark)
benchmark.names <- benchmark.names[2:length(benchmark)] # Skip first column to exclude date column

data <- read.csv("data.csv") # Read in data
data.names <- colnames(data)
data.names <- data.names[2:length(data)] # Skip first column to exclude date column

for(i in data[, data.names]){
    tmp <- data.frame()
    for(k in benchmark[, benchmark.names]){
        tmp <- data[, i]/benchmark[, k]
    }
div <- rbind(div,tmp)
}
```

Some extra information: ultimately, I want to use these divided time series for Mann-Kendall trend testing.
Any thoughts on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply`

```
 lst <- lapply(data, function(x) x[col(benchmark[-1])]/benchmark[-1])
```

If we need to `rbind` the output

```
 do.call(rbind, lst)
```